# is it ok to pass variable through the url in phonegap?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

When creating a jquery mobile / phonegap app, is it ok to pass variables through the url from one page to another

```
page.html?var1=foo&var2=bar
```

or is does it create a problem when compiling the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just fine to pass variables to external pages. Just know that URL variables will **only** be passed to external pages. Meaning that if you already have an external page in the DOM, you will have to re-load the page to pass it variables again.

I believe that older versions of jQuery Mobile hamper this behavior but you should be good to go with anything 1.0 or later.

Also read the bottom of this page, "Known Limitations": http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html (specifically the second from the bottom bullet)

## Update

To reload a page with jQuery Mobile you can use the `$.mobile.changePage()` function and set the `reloadPage` option to `true`:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-link-id', 'click', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage({ reloadPage : true });
    return false;
});
```

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: what is the best way to reload the page?

Comment: @Jason See the **update** to my answer. You can hi-jack the clicks on whatever links you want to and use `$.mobile.changePage()` manually to refresh external pages.

Answer (score 0):

it "works", however it's not the best way.
Apps should be all one page with dynamically retrieved and displayed content.