# Can you use a variable in a url path?

Tags: javascript, html

My app has html pages with content in different languages. Id like to use a variable (that is set when selecting a language) in a url like this:

```
<a href="/language/*variable*/product.html">
```

edit: I got marked down so to add more info lets says I set this when the page loads

```
var language = english;
```

There will be links in the app to change that to other languages ;-)

Comment: What's your technology stack ?

Comment: Its a phonegap app so just html / jQuery

Comment: This questions looks similar to yours, maybe you'll find a hint there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951245/is-it-ok-to-pass-variable-through-the-url-in-phonegap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767460/how-to-pass-url-parameter-in-phonegap-and-jquerymobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your  tag look like this

```
<a id="link" href="#">Click Me!</a>
```

Let your *variable* be called prod.
Add these lines to your javascript wherever you want to update the url.

```
var hyperl = document.getElementById("link");
hyperl.href = "/language/" + prod + "/product.html";
```

EDIT: 
Use this HTML

```
<a id="link" href="/language/LANG/product.html">Click Me!</a>
```

Use this javascript (or similar) to make all links point to the same language (variable name *prod*):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    var hyperl = links[i];
    hyperl.href.replace(LANG, prod);
}
```

Comment: my app has a LOT of links so using an ID for each one wouldn't work.

Comment: @MarkL: Do you want all of them to point to the same language of different ones?

Comment: There will be English / Spanish / German. When the page loads i set var language = english; - links on the page can change the language var

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to dynamically generate the URL.

```
var string = '/language/'+variable+'product.html';
$(a#language).attr('href', string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Javascript function to dynamically replace all `href` attributes of any `<a>` tags on the page like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script>
"use strict";
function setLanguage(lang) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
  for (var e = 0; e < elements.length; ++e)
  { elements[e].href = elements[e].href.replace(/\?hl=[A-za-z]*/, "?hl=" + lang); }
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Search with Google</h1>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;q=python">Search for <b>Python</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;q=ruby">Search for <b>Ruby</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;q=javascript">Search for <b>Javascript</b></a></li>
    </ol>
    <br>
    <small>
      Language: 
      <a href="#" onclick="setLanguage('en')">en</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="setLanguage('de')">de</a>
    </small>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the example above, the `?hl=xxx` part of the url is replaced via a regex whenever one of the `en` or `de` buttons is pressed.